# How install latest Extension Library if I already have UP1?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I need the latest Extension Library....
But now I have UP1 installed on my server Domino (Linux) and Designer.

What's the correct procedure to remove the UP1 and install last Extension Library?

Tnx

Comment: which part do you need of the Extension Library. If you only need the Social features and Retional stuff (extlibx part). You can install the extlibx part on top of the UP1. It is not supported, but it works ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Server**

To uninstall UP1 on Linux execute `./uninstall` from the directory with the install files.

This is documented at http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Installing_the_upgrade_pack_on_a_Domino_server_ddxl853.

You can then install Extension Library on your server using the Update Site method as documented here:
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPages_Extension_Library_Deployment

---

**Client**

You uninstall UP1 from Domino Designer using the standard Windows Add/Remove Programs option in the Control Panel (look for "Lotus Notes 8.5.3 Upgrade Pack 1") and then install the extension library in the client by following this:
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Installing_the_OpenNTF_update_site_in_Domino_Designer_ddxl853